Is there any way we can deploy an MFE without providing a host app in build process in module federation?
i have a MFE which shares redux toolkit from my host. i want to remove my host during build process. Actually i want to remove a strong dependency of host in remote build process. Is it possible?
My app both host and remote are in react-vite-typescript and federation used is: @originjs/vite-plugin-federation
